# Python LXML XPATH Returns Error With Valid Query

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am running the following query:

```
//div[@class="review-list"]//div[@class="review review--with-sidebar"]//div[@class="review-content"]/p/string(.)
```

I get the following error:

> lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

However, if I use the following notation:

```
//div[@class="review-list"]//div[@class="review review--with-sidebar"]//div[@class="review-content"]/p/text()
```

All is well.

I assume the issue is with the use of the `string(.)` notation, but when I test it [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi) it comes up fine, so I'm assuming its valid syntax.

I'm essentially running the following code:

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring(PAGE_CONTENT)
results = tree.xpath(QUERY)
```

Is there an alternative method I could be using that will allow the use of expressions like this? `string-join` seems to cause similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your error is that the notation

```
.../string(.)
```

is only valid in XPath 2.0 or above. In XPath 1.0 it is invalid and throws an error.

An alternative that is valid in XPath-1.0 would be wrapping the whole expression in the `string(...)` function like this:

```
string(//div[@class="review-list"]//div[@class="review review--with-sidebar"]//div[@class="review-content"]/p)
```

Comment: Dang, thanks friend. Wrapping it in a string unfortunately concatenates all results. And `BLAH/string(p)` likewise throws an error. Will have to revisit the drawing board me thinks.